# Как передать несколько форм с одним id с помощью jquery serialize?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Создаю динамически несколько блоков с формами в которых *input'ы*, по ajax передаю с помощью *serialize()*, но на выходе получаю информацию только из первого блока. Как получить из обоих?

**JS**

```
var msg = $('#sending_form');
$.ajax({
  url: 'sending.php',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: msg.serialize(), 
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data){
    $('#results').html(data);
  }})
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="sending_form"><input type="text" name="username[]" id="username" class="form-control"></form>
<form action="" method="post" id="sending_form"><input type="text" name="username[]" id="username" class="form-control"></form>
```

Comment: id разных элементов не могут совпадать, это некорректный html-код, ставьте разные id

Comment: если я к форме присвою класс, вместо id и буду выбирать по нему, то это будет корректно?

Comment: Да. . . . . . .